# Cannot mock copyfile when imported from shutil

Tags: python, mocking, shutil

This is taking an embarassing amount to figure out but I'm trying to mock copyfile when used in the module targeted for testing.
The method is used as so in the module:

```
from shutil import copyfile

class ModuleName:
   @staticmethod
   def method_being_tested():
      ...
      copyfile(source, destination)
```

However, all calls to mock are ignored.  I've tried decorating the unit test with:

```
@patch.object(shutil, 'copyfile')
@patch('shutil.copyfile')
@patch('ModuleName.copyfile')
```

But still copyfile continues to run.  Can anyone give me any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to patch it *where* it is being imported. Let's say the file where `ModuleName` lives is called `my_class.py`. In order to properly mock it you would need to do `@patch(path.to.my_class.py)`. Below is a short example illustrating this.

```
# demo/my_class.py

from shutil import copyfile

class ModuleName:
    @staticmethod
    def method_being_tested(source, destination):
        copyfile(source, destination)

# test_my_class.py

from unittest.mock import patch
from demo.my_class import ModuleName


@patch("demo.my_class.copyfile")
def test_my_module(mock_copy):
    ModuleName.method_being_tested(1, 2)
    mock_copy.assert_called_once()
```

Running the above succeeds and shows that we successfully mocked `copyfile`. It might benefit you to read about *where* to patch as shown in the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).